# Angular Material 2 - How to center align with reduced width

Tags: css, angular-material

**Here is my html**

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>One</template>
    <template md-tab-content>
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
      </md-content>
    </template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Two</template>
    <template md-tab-content>
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
      </md-content>
    </template>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

This take full width on desktop and mobile,What changes are needed for the content to be rendered with 50% width in desktop and center aligned?

Answer (score -1):

this is all HTML and you're not showing what you're doing with the styling (CSS).

with bootstrap, you can add the following two classes "col-md-6 col-offset-md-3" will do what you're looking for. like this:

```
<md-tab-group class="col-md-6 col-offset-md-3">
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>One</template>
    <template md-tab-content>
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
      </md-content>
    </template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Two</template>
    <template md-tab-content>
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
      </md-content>
    </template>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```